# What is the standard and professional way to query Laravel polymorphic relations?

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-relationship

Trying to fetch persons table based on the result of the polymorphic relations. What is the professional standard way on doing this? Thank you very much!

Insertable model

```
public function insertables() {
return $this->morphMany(Insertable::class, 'insertable');
}
```

Person model

```
public function insertable () {
return $this->morphTo();    
}

$people = Person::find($id)->insertables;
$peopleIds = $people->pluck('person_id');
return response()->json(Person::whereIn('id', $peopleIds)->get());
```

Comment: try this [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#customizing-the-pivot-attribute-name) you can pass na argument within the with paramerter